# How do I attach my app's log file to an email in Android?

Tags: android, logging, android-logcat

I know this has been asked, but I haven't found a clear answer. My app allows the user to email the developer and I would like to attach a log file if it exists. How can I do that?

Also, are there any permissions I will need to declare?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that there is no way from Android framework how to do that. But I am also interested in the sending silent logs of my applications, because a lot of users just tap no, if Android is asking for sending the logs.

It should be possible to do that with ACRA library, I didn't try that yet. But I am planning.

Have a look on:

[ACRA basic](http://www.toptal.com/android/automated-android-crash-reports-with-acra-and-cloudant)

and

[ACRA project - sending logs by email](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-by-email)

I hope it will help